# Topology: If $G\subset E, G$ is open and $E$ satisfies $\overline{E^0}\subset G$. Prove $G$ is closed too.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $G\subset E, G$ is open and $E$ satisfies $\overline{E^0}\subset G$. Prove $G$ is closed too.

I'm relatively new to topology and the following is what I "THINK" I've proven but not exactly sure. I would really appreciate if someone corrected me if I'm wrong or if there is more direct way to do this as I don't feel too confident in my proof.

For reference these are the definitions I was given and therefore been using for the proof.

$x\in\overline{A}\iff\forall(G\in\tau, x\in G),(G\cap A\neq\emptyset=\exists y\in G\cap A)$.

$x\in A^0\iff\exists G\in\tau,x\in G\subset A$.

$x\in A^a\iff\forall(G\in\tau,x\in G),\exists y\neq x\in G\cap A$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Assume $G\subset E, G\in\tau$ and $E$ satisfies $\overline{E^0}\subset G$.

Consider $x\in\overline{E^0}$. Then $x\in G$.

Thus, $\exists y\in G\cap E^0$ and consequently $y\in G$ and $y\in E^0$.

Since $y\in E^0, \exists G\in\tau, y\in G\subset E$ and thus $y\in E$.

Then $y\in E$ and $y\in G\Rightarrow \exists y\neq x\in E\cap G$.

Hence $x\in G^a$.

Since $x\in G$ then $G^a\subset G$.

By definition, $G$ must be closed as well.

QED

I feel like this is totally wrong but at least I feel like I'm in the right track. I do know that a set is closed if it's complement is open but I didn't know how to formulate the proof in that manner. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $G\subset E,$ then $G^\circ \subset E^\circ$ and thus $\overline{G^\circ}\subset \overline{E^\circ}\subset G.$ Since $G$ is open, $G=G^\circ,$ hence $\overline{G}\subset G.$ This shows $G=\overline{G}$ and therefore $G$ is closed.

Comment: Well now I feel foolish but thank you for that. Yours is a more direct way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Much faster: as $G\subset E\implies G\subset E^\circ$
and
$\overline{E^\circ}\subset G$
we have
$$E^\circ\subset\overline{E^\circ}\subset G\subset E^\circ$$
and $G = \overline{E^\circ}$ is closed.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you.